# Accessing localStorage using Native WebView in React-Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, webkit, wkwebview

In my RN project, I am using Native WebView component. WebKit webview for android and WKWebView for iOS.
I am trying to load a web page in webview which has this `localStorage.clear();` function in JS file and page is throwing error

> cannot read property clear of null;

In this case, localStorage variable is null.
Is there a way to provide localStorage to native webview?